# Pathwise bound for Ito integral

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, upper-lower-bounds

The following question has been puzzling to me and there has been no luck trying to resolve it. Perhaps I am missing something. So, any help would be very much appreciated.

If $f\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ is a smooth deterministic function, from Ito formula, we can have
$$ \int_0^t f(s) dB_s = f(t)B_t - \int_0^t B_sdf(s) \,.  $$
Therefore, 
$$ \Big|\int_0^t f(s) dB_s \Big| \leq C_t ( ||f||_\infty + ||f'||_\infty)\sup_{0\leq s \leq t}|B_s| \,.  $$
However, the situation is not as good when we make $f$ random. I am wondering if there's a similar result as the above if we're able to have some sort of bounds, say,
$$ | f (t,\omega)| + |f'(t,\omega)| \leq C$$ for all $t$ and $\omega$?

---

I've just corrected a typo in the question.

Comment: How does the randomness of $f$ interact with the randomness of $B$ ? If $f(s,\cdot)$ is not adapted, you cannot even define the stochastic integral in general...

Comment: Ah, yes. Assuming you have all the adaptedness. The example I have in mind is that $f(t,\omega) = g(B_t,t)$.

Comment: @S.V. What exactly do you mean by "something similar"? Note that the stochastic integral has a (modification with) continuous sample paths and therefore the paths are bounded on compact $t$-sets with probability $1$.

Comment: @saz: I think what I have in mind is an inequality that is like $$|\int_0^t f(s) dB_s| \leq C_t \sup_{0\leq s \leq t} | B_s|.$$ The $C_t$ here is only dependent on the universal bound of $f$ and $f'$ and independent of the realization you take. I suspect this is true but haven't been able to prove it. This is sort of a pathwise Poincare inequality in my mind.